# docker image in gitlab CI used for create docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, docker-image

I want to build docker with "ready to run" application in docker CI, so to do that I have created in .gitlab-ci.yml this code:

```
rebuild base docker:
  stage: prepear
  image: docker
  script:
    - docker build -t base_django environment
```

I want to use the official docker image to do it (image: docker), of course in directory environment I have placed Dockerfile. Unfortunately job faild on:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.8.0 (4745a6f3)
  on docker-auto-scale 72989761
Using Docker executor with image docker ...
Pulling docker image docker ...
Using docker image sha256:639de9917ae1f2e4a586893c9a6ea3f21fd774bc4037184ecac35f3153a293b5 for docker ...
Running on runner-72989761-project-9841176-concurrent-0 via runner-72989761-srm-1552402128-c63119b1...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/*****/*****'...
Checking out a804a12f as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ docker build -t base_django environment
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: You need to install docker, if it's already installed, add your current user to docker group.

Comment: I have used docker image called "docker", as I saw in similar examples docker is installed and I only need do use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a specific configuration to run docker in docker with Gitlab CI. You can find more information right here : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at the end of article you have provided is full example. In this example I can see that in each job in test stage docker image is pulled and run by docker command, I think about solution where in build stage i push image to registry and in next stages I will use it by image: my_image in gitlab-ci.yml. Is my idea wrong?

Comment: if you want to test the image after the build, push it to registry and use in the the same or next stage. you can use docker executor with your image name to run it